# QML TreeView get the click event for second child only

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I have a TreeView and I am generating C++ model using `QStandardItemModel` class.
I want to get the click event when user clicks on every 2nd child in the tree.

```
Item-1
  |
  |
  Item-1.1   <-- Detect click on this Item
  |    |
  |    Item-1.1.1        
  |    Item-1.1.2
  |
  Item-1.2   <-- Detect click on this Item
  |    |
  |    Item-1.2.1        
  |    Item-1.2.2
  |
Item-2
  |
  |
  Item-2.1   <-- Detect click on this Item
  |    |
  |    Item-2.1.1        
  |    Item-2.1.2
  |
```

I have tried below code to detect the click but it is generating click for 3rd level child also.

```
TreeView {
  model: myCppModel
  onClicked: {
    if (index.parent.row >= 0) {
        if (index.row > 0) {
           console.log(myCppModel.data(index));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify the question. It is absolutely unclear what do you ask.